# How to define a javascript variable with a hiphen?

Tags: javascript, variables

I need to evaluate a string such as `employee-count = 3` where I have an object with potential variables that could be referenced. I have no problem when the variable name is valid, but with something like `employee-count` I am a little stumped.

Here is my sample for normal variable names:

```
function evalWithObject(expression, object) {
  _.each(object, (value, key) => {
    eval(`var ${key} = value`);
  });

  return eval(expression.replace('=', '==='));
}
```

Is there any way I can define a variable in the current scope with object notation? For example I could do `object['employee-count'] = true` with no problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can define variable names with a hyphen. The compiler would interpret it as a subtraction.

Comment: That all said, you could do `this["my-key"] = "Hello world"; console.log(this["my-key"]);` and it would output `"Hello world"`.

Comment: Though, at that point, what do you gain by doing `this["key"]` instead of `object["key"]` , other than an unnecessary loop?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by using a hyphen? they is underscore.

Comment: @TylerRoper that is true. One solution I was thinking of id searching the expression for each key, and adding `object.` to the front of it. That way it looks for each on the object

Answer (score 1):

You can't use hyphen in a variable name as you may know but there may be a potential work around which is to replace keys (I have hyphen replaced with underscrore for instance) and use eval in global scope.

```
// if you want to create variable in global space, indirect eval call
var geval = window.execScript || eval; 
function evalWithObject(expression, object) {
  for (var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {        
        value = object[key];
        key = key.replace('-', '_');        
        geval('var ' + key + ' = ' + value);
        // OR
        // eval.call(null, 'var ' + key + ' = ' + value)
    }
  }
  return geval(expression.replace('=', '==='));
  // OR
  // return eval.call(null, expression.replace('=', '==='));
}

// you need to control your expession though, replace key employee-count to employee_count 
evalWithObject("employee_count = 5 ? console.log('Yes')  : console.log('No') " , {"employee-count": 5});

// log variable
console.log(window['employee_count']);
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, my only worry being if there is a `-` in there as subtraction this will get replaced as well. I think I can loop through the keys, search for the key in the expression and replace it with the underscore-converted key. That way just the variable names get replaced. Thanks!

Comment: If the expression has hyphen, you may have to add further logic to handle that for sure. But its just a way of showing how it can be achieved.